# Makefile generation in MonoDevelop

Tags: makefile, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm playing around with MonoDevelop on Mint12 Linux and seem to be having problems with getting it to generate Makefiles.  I create a new GTK# solution, test that it does indeed create a blank window when run, and then hit Project -> Generate Makefiles.

The following is the output in the Tool output window:

```
Generating Makefiles for Solution test2

Creating Makefile for Solution test2

Creating Makefile for Project test2

Makefiles could not be generated: . Cannot handle unknown runtime version ClrVersion.'Net_4_0'.
```

---

any help finding a solution to this would be appreciated.  My ultimate goal is to figure out the process involved in generating a .DEB file.

Answer (score 2):

You installed the IDE, but not all the development tools.  Go into Mint's package manager and install this:

*mono-complete:
This is a metapackage and pulls in the Mono runtime, development tools and all libraries.*